# for what $g$, $\int f(x+\theta)g(x)=0$ implies $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering for what $g$ ,$\int_0^{\infty} f(x+\theta)g(x)\mathrm dx=0$ for all $\theta\in \mathbb R$ implies $f(x)=0$, a.e.

This is true when $g$ is constant. I think there should be a much weaker condition. But I have not made any progress yet.

Oh, I find the convolution theory quite fits the problem. Is it true that either $f(x)=0$ a.e. or $g(x)=0$ a.e.? (If my understanding does not go wrong)

There's another question:
Suppose $g(x)>0$. Is there a simple proof for $f(x)=0$ a.e.?

Comment: @geetha290krm: I think it is actually true for g constant, since the integral is only over the positive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

if $f,g\in L^1(R)$ and if the Fourier transform of $g$ has no zero, your condition implies $f=0.$

Comment: Thanks. I think I should go learn something about Fourier transform.